# Elastic Beanstalk application deployment fails from EBExtension failing to install

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We're using Elastic Beanstalk, (Postgres, Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.2.0) and I woke up today to a Severe Health warning, causing all requests to respond with a 502 Bad Gateway. I haven't manually deployed since 4/9/19, so not sure why this happened all of a sudden.

The original error we got was:

```
Application deployment failed at 2019-04-18T15:39:51Z with exit status 1 and error: Package listed in EBExtension failed to install.

Yum does not have postgresql96-devel available for installation.
```

The repo I inherited is a little untidy, and I found instance of `postgres96-devel` in three different files:

- .ebextensions/config.yml
- .ebextensions/proxy.config
- proxy.config

My config.yml file looks like:

```
packages:
  rpm:
    postgresql: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
  yum:
    postgresql96-devel: []
    perl-CPAN: []
```

I noticed the rpm link returns a 404, and when looking for a better url, I saw this warning on the [Postgres RPM page](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php):

> As of 15 April 2019, there is only one repository RPM per distro, and
>   it includes repository information for all available PostgreSQL
>   releases

What I've tried:

- Redeploying the last successful build from 4/9/19
- Changing the config.yml file to look like

// obviously I'm thrashing here

```
packages:
  rpm:
    postgresql: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
  yum:
    postgresql11-devel: []
    perl-CPAN: []
```

- [According to this AWS support article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-health-enhanced-notifications.html), I terminated the instance and let EB bring up a new instance.

With all these trials + redeploying, I still seeing errors like:

Application deployment failed at 2019-04-18T17:40:41Z with exit status 1 and error: Package listed in EBExtension failed to install.

> Yum does not have postgresql96-devel available for installation.
>   Incorrect application version "app-v1_4_1-190418_084747" (deployment
>   98). Expected version "app-v1_4_1-190409_140626" (deployment 104).
>   Process default has been unhealthy for 42 minutes
>   (Target.FailedHealthChecks).

I'm not sure why it's complaining about postgres96-devel since I changed my config file to point to postgres11-devel.

Any ideas how to get things back up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get everything back up and running. Here's what I think happened.

- Our prod instances were running Linux 3.2. This did not contain the correct rpm package, so it relied on the rpm link from config.yml.
- That url broke as of 4/15/19, so when EB went to deploy and pull that RPM, it failed, causing the entire deployment to fail.
- The fix was to simply downgrade the yum package from postresql96-devel to postgres95-devel. Linux 3.2's yum directory contained postgres95-devel, so the deployment was able to skip going out to the internet to download the rpm (which at this point was broken).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the PostgreSQL 9.6 using the `amazon-linux-extra` tool:
(if using docker, in a Dockerfile: )

```
RUN amazon-linux-extras install postgresql9.6
```